# iPhone Custom leftBarButtonItem fashing on popViewControllerAnimated:YES

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, viewdidload

I've added custom back button to my viewController.

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(backClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
    [customBarItem release];
```

But, leftBarButtonItem is flashing:

```
-(void)backClicked:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Can you help me disabling flashing on back button pressed?

Comment: solved by adding: [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];